# Understanding the ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a skip thought model using tensorflow and a current version is placed [here](https://gist.github.com/b7858fd7f6e9e137f029cf391faee5e2).
[image]

Currently I using one GPU of my machine (total 2 GPUs) and the GPU info is

```
2017-09-06 11:29:32.657299: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties:
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.683
pciBusID 0000:02:00.0
Total memory: 10.91GiB
Free memory: 10.75GiB
```

However, I got OOM when I'm trying to feed data to the model. I try to debug as follow:

I use the following snippet right after I run `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())`

```
    logger.info('Total: {} params'.format(
        np.sum([
            np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list())
            for v in tf.trainable_variables()
        ])))
```

and got `2017-09-06 11:29:51,333 INFO main main.py:127 - Total: 62968629 params`, roughly about `240Mb` if all using `tf.float32`. The output of `tf.global_variables` is

```
[<tf.Variable 'embedding/embedding_matrix:0' shape=(155229, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'encoder/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'encoder/rnn/gru_cell/gates/bias:0' shape=(400,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'encoder/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/kernel:0' shape=(400, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'encoder/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/bias:0' shape=(200,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/weights:0' shape=(200, 155229) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/biases:0' shape=(155229,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/previous_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/previous_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/gates/bias:0' shape=(400,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/previous_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/kernel:0' shape=(400, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/previous_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/bias:0' shape=(200,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/next_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/gates/kernel:0' shape=(400, 400) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/next_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/gates/bias:0' shape=(400,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/next_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/kernel:0' shape=(400, 200) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'decoder/next_decoder/rnn/gru_cell/candidate/bias:0' shape=(200,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'global_step:0' shape=() dtype=int32_ref>]
```

In my training phrase, I have a data array whose shape is `(164652, 3, 30)`, namely `sample_size x 3 x time_step`, the `3` here means the previous sentence, current sentence and next sentence. The size of this training data is about `57Mb` and is stored in a `loader`. Then I use write a generator function to get the sentences, looks like

```
def iter_batches(self, batch_size=128, time_major=True, shuffle=True):

    num_samples = len(self._sentences)
    if shuffle:
        samples = self._sentences[np.random.permutation(num_samples)]
    else:
        samples = self._sentences

    batch_start = 0
    while batch_start < num_samples:
        batch = samples[batch_start:batch_start + batch_size]

        lens = (batch != self._vocab[self._vocab.pad_token]).sum(axis=2)
        y, x, z = batch[:, 0, :], batch[:, 1, :], batch[:, 2, :]
        if time_major:
            yield (y.T, lens[:, 0]), (x.T, lens[:, 1]), (z.T, lens[:, 2])
        else:
            yield (y, lens[:, 0]), (x, lens[:, 1]), (z, lens[:, 2])
        batch_start += batch_size
```

The training loop looks like

```
for epoch in num_epochs:
    batches = loader.iter_batches(batch_size=args.batch_size)
    try:
        (y, y_lens), (x, x_lens), (z, z_lens) =  next(batches)
        _, summaries, loss_val = sess.run(
        [train_op, train_summary_op, st.loss],
        feed_dict={
            st.inputs: x,
            st.sequence_length: x_lens,
            st.previous_targets: y,
            st.previous_target_lengths: y_lens,
            st.next_targets: z,
            st.next_target_lengths: z_lens
        })
    except StopIteraton:
        ...
```

Then I got a OOM. If I comment out the whole `try` body (no to feed data), the script run just fine.

I have no idea why I got OOM in such a small data scale. Using `nvidia-smi` I always got

```
Wed Sep  6 12:03:37 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 384.59                 Driver Version: 384.59                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   44C    P2    60W / 275W |  10623MiB / 11172MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  GeForce GTX 108...  Off  | 00000000:03:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   43C    P2    62W / 275W |  10621MiB / 11171MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     32748    C   python3                                      10613MiB |
|    1     32748    C   python3                                      10611MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I *can't* see the *actual* GPU usage of my script since tensorflow always steals all memory at the beginning. And the actual problem here is I don't know how to debug this.

I've read some posts about OOM on StackOverflow. Most of them happened when feeding a large test set data to the model and feeding the data by small batches can avoid the problem. But I don't why see such a small data and param combination sucks in my 11Gb 1080Ti, since the error it just try to allocate a matrix sized `[3840 x 155229]`. (The output matrix of the decoder, `3840 = 30(time_steps) x 128(batch_size)`, `155229` is vocab_size).

```
2017-09-06 12:14:45.787566: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:277] ********************************************************************************************xxxxxxxx
2017-09-06 12:14:45.787597: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3840,155229]
2017-09-06 12:14:45.788735: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1158] Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3840,155229]
     [[Node: decoder/previous_decoder/Add = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](decoder/previous_decoder/MatMul, decoder/biases/read)]]
2017-09-06 12:14:45.790453: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 2857 get requests, put_count=2078 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.481232 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.657683
2017-09-06 12:14:45.790482: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1139, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1121, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3840,155229]
     [[Node: decoder/previous_decoder/Add = Add[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](decoder/previous_decoder/MatMul, decoder/biases/read)]]
     [[Node: GradientDescent/update/_146 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_2166_GradientDescent/update", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: "skip thought"! pretty cool name for a model.

Answer (score 33):

Let's divide the issues one by one:

About tensorflow to allocate all memory in advance, you can use following code snippet to let tensorflow allocate memory whenever it is needed. So that you can understand how the things are going.

```
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(allow_growth=True)
session = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

This works equally with `tf.Session()` instead of `tf.InteractiveSession()` if you prefer.

Second thing about the sizes, 
As there is no information about your network size, we cannot estimate what is going wrong. However, you can alternatively debug step by step all the network. For example, create a network only with one layer, get its output, create session and feed values once and visualize how much memory you consume. Iterate this debugging session until you see the point where you are going out of memory.

Please be aware that 3840 x 155229 output is really, REALLY a big output. It means ~600M neurons, and ~2.22GB per one layer only. If you have any similar size layers, all of them will add up to fill your GPU memory pretty fast.

Also, this is only for forward direction, if you are using this layer for training, the back propagation and layers added by optimizer will multiply this size by 2. So, for training you consume ~5 GB just for output layer.

I suggest you to revise your network and try to reduce batch size / parameter counts to fit your model to GPU

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I'll try the `gpu_options` soon. About the network size, isn't the snippet `np.sum([np.prod(v.get_shape().as_list()) for v in tf.trainable_variables()])` getting the whole number `(62968629)` params of the network? Doubled with the gradients, total `2 * 62968629 * 4 / 1024/1024/1024 -> 0.47G`. And, I have only `1` layer in my encoder, and `1` layer in my `2` decoders. The `3840 x 155229` is the decoder output, not about the params, so I think it would not double when back propagating ?

Comment: This calculation is correct for inference. I thought you made a fully connected layer, my bad. However, for training, you need to use tf.global_variables() rather than trainable_variables() as optimizers and all other appendixes that you implement will add more invisible parameters.

Comment: Thanks again. I printed the result of `tf.global_variables()` and `tf.trainable_variables()` and updated the question. In my situation, the latter only lack the `global_step` tensor comparing to the former.

Comment: New TF 2.0 way to allocate memory like this: ```gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
for gpu in gpus: tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)```

Comment: TF2 got rid of tf.config AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'config'

Answer (score 26):

This may not make sense technically but after experimenting for some time, this is what I have found out.

**ENVIRONMENT: Ubuntu 16.04**

---

When you run the command

> nvidia-smi

You will get the total memory consumption of the installed Nvidia graphic card. An example is as shown in this image [image]

When you have run your neural network your consumption may change to look like [image]

The memory consumption is typically given to python. For some strange reason, if this process fails to terminate successfully, the memory is never freed. If you try running another instance of the neural network application, you are bout to receive a memory allocation error. The hard way is to try to figure out a way to terminate this process using the process ID. Example, with process ID 2794, you can do

```
sudo kill -9 2794
```

The simple way, is to just restart your computer and try again. If it is a code related bug however, this will not work.

If the above mentioned process does not work,it is likely you are using a data batch size that can not fit into GPU or CPU memory.

What you can do is to reduce the batch size or the spatial dimensions (length, width and depth) of your input data. This may work but you may run out of RAM.

The surest way to conserve RAM is to use a function generator and that is subject matter on its own.

Comment: Terminating process using 'kill' worked for me - so that's the easy way.

Comment: Ever since this answer was posted I have been doing a lot of "upper arrow + enter" in the terminal when my ML model is training... Thanks!

Comment: @Acy try `watch nvidia-smi` :)

Comment: well hot damn you just saved my bacon!

Comment: thanks a lot, nice explanation, this was the case for me.

Answer (score 13):

You are exhausting your memory, You can reduce the batch size, which would slow down the training process but let you fit the data.

Answer (score 5):

I know your question was about `tensorflow`. Anyhow, using `Keras` with a `tensorflow`-backend was my use-case and resulted in the same *OOM*-Error.

My solution using Keras with `tf-backend` was to use Keras' `fit_generator()`-method. Previous to that I only used the `fit()`-method (resulting in the *OOM*-Error).

`fit_generator()` is normally useful if you cannot fit your data into your main memory or have to access CPU-ressoures parallel to GPU-training. For example see this extract from the docs:

> *The generator is run in parallel to the model, for efficiency. For instance, this allows you to do real-time data augmentation on images on CPU in parallel to training your model on GPU.*

Apparently, this can also help to prevent memory-overflow from your graphic cards memory.

---

*Edit: If you need some inspiration on how to develop your own (threadsafe) generator extending Keras' `Sequence`-class, which then can be used for `fit_generator()`, you might look at some information I provided in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441216/on-fit-generator-and-thread-safety/56459978#56459978).*

Comment: Me to future me: I lowered the batch size, input size(not desired), and increased `steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: @NelsonGon: Sounds correct since the batches are parallelized and, thus, the batch size corresponds to your memory consumption.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened to me when I was applying transfer learning using an EfficientNet model. I was able to solve this by freezing the Conv-layers:

```
base_model = EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, input_tensor=...)
for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a memory issue. In my case, I just reduce the batch size.

Answer (score 0):

You may reduce the batch size, although you might find that the result (model's performance) differ (usually lower performance) than when you use bigger batch size. Some models might perform well when batch size is bigger. They may be able to converge faster. Otherwise, the model may need more epochs when batch size is smaller. In this case, training time may take longer, especially now that you have added more epochs and employed smaller batch size.

There is no solution for longer training time than to be patience, because it means that you need GPU with bigger RAM if you want faster computation :)

Answer (score -3):

Restarting jupyter notebook worked for me

Comment: This worked for me too. Even if I closed the browser, nvidia-smi kept the memory usage. I had to close the Jupyter Notebook console as well. Then the memory was freed and I could start Jupyter again and run the exact same code with no OOM errors!