# Error of using tensorflow-gpu on custom object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use the tensorflow-gpu for my custom object detection. I have created conda environment, downloaded and installed CUDA and CuDNN 10.0 with my tensorflow-gpu version 1.14. However, I have received this error

```
ResourceExhaustedError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,1792,1792,3,2] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator gpu_host_bfc
     [[{{node Tile_5}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

  (1) Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[32,1792,1792,3,2] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator gpu_host_bfc
     [[{{node Tile_5}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[training/Adam/cond_175/Switch_2/_6707]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

By following this website [Train Object Detection AI with 6 lines of code](https://medium.com/deepquestai/train-object-detection-ai-with-6-lines-of-code-6d087063f6ff).

Comment: Your computer doesn't have enough RAM to run this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding the ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066850/understanding-the-resourceexhaustederror-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shape)

Comment: @NicolasGervais, I have 8GB RAM, I have looked into the posts you gave to me. It did give me an error. I will give you back the error later because I am currently running a code using my own CPU