# Tensorflow Throws Exception when using GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to accelerate a model I've built with keras and after some difficulty with cuda library versions I've managed to get tensorflow to detect my GPU. However now when I run the model with my GPU detected, it fails with the following traceback:

```html
2021-01-20 17:40:26.549946: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:441] ****___*********____________________________________________________________________________________
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model.py", line 72, in <module>
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 888, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2942, in __call__
    return graph_function._call_flat(
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1918, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 555, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/home/muke/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  SameWorkerRecvDone unable to allocate output tensor. Key: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0;ccc21c10a2feabe0;/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0;edge_17_IteratorGetNext;0:0
     [[{{node IteratorGetNext/_2}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_train_function_875]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The model runs fine on just CPU.

I'm unsure if this is related to the versioning or not, but to be sure I'll detail the situation. I'm running gentoo but due to how heavy the tensorflow package is to compile I've downloaded a binary package through pip, which has version `2.4.0`. I've installed the lastest `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package as well as `cudnn` through my distro's package manager, but when I do this and test to see if tensorflow detects my GPU, it says it can't find `libcusolver.so.10`, when instead I have `libcusolver.so.11` through the latest version. I tried to downgrade to a version of the cuda toolkit which had `libcusolver.so.10`, but then tensorflow would complain about not being able to find several other version 11 libraries, so I've installed the latest cuda toolkit package but included in the `/opt/cuda/lib64` directory the older `libcusolver.so.10` files as well. I understand this is a hacky solution but I'm not sure what else I can do if that's what it's looking for.

Here's my full model code using keras:

```html
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(8, (7,7), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Conv2D(16, (7,7), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.summary()

batch_size = 1000
epochs = 100

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001), metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, verbose=2, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Comment: doesn't "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError:  SameWorkerRecvDone unable to allocate output tensor" simply mean that you ran out of memory, possibly on the GPU? Also, simply copying over a few libraries seems like a surefire way to break things. seems like tf2.4 and cuda 11 should work fine: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46066850/understanding-the-resourceexhaustederror-oom-when-allocating-tensor-with-shape)

Comment: What is the input image dataset size you are using for this model definition?